# How to configure different ES targets for different parts of a TypeScript project?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am starting to convert a JS codebase to TS and the codebase has different parts, some internal that I want to compile to the newest target possible and some external that I want to compile so they are as backwards compatible as possible.

How to set up `tsconfig.json` to do so? Is it even possible with one `tsconfig.json`? the `compilerOptions` option is for the whole project, right?